# Visual Studio 2017 TestMethod No error on run, just after

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, vs-unit-testing-framework

Hi diddaly hodely neighboronies!

I am currently making a test project to make sure my project is working correctly.

[image]

All of the tests work fine except one.  It finishes the test with no errors as seen below...

[image]

It then updates the Passed Tests list...

[image]

However, a few seconds later when it's done it outputs this message:

> An exception occurred while invoking executor
>   'executor://mstestadapter/v2': Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

[image]

And the test is no longer lit up indicating passed.

[image]

Me and a friend have been googling this all day and have found the issue on a few pages, with completely different answers, none of which solved our problem.

Has anyone else had this issue and solved it?  Please share!

Comment: looks like you can blame MS instead of yourself this time :)

Comment: Haha for reals!

Comment: Does the test class have any cleanup code or finalizers defined? It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Elaborate.  What do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a DLL that was being executed but didn't report back errors.  I doubt this will help many people, but check your references and make sure it has what it's looking for.  I'm assuming this is because it's using the Test path instead of the project it's tied to.  Good luck to those who are haunted by this issue.

UPDATE: Yup it was the reference issue, but it is running on a separate thread.  Youch!  Check your threads!